# Word for the "original purpose of a solution"?

Tags: single-word-requests

I am trying to say in good quality English that a certain idea which was implemented is currently used way beyond the scope it was intended for. It was a gap-filler which we are now basing our entire solution and this is going to be unsustainable.

I am trying to write something like "This architecture has exceeded it's original ____ and needs major refactoring"
I know there's a word exactly for this... I keep coming up with "premise" or "precinct" (I know the word I am looking for sounds something like these, not saying they are applicable).

I've already used "purpose" a lot, in a different context, and I need to avoid using purpose for this statement to prevent confusion.

Comment: "Its original " not "it's original".

Comment: If you drop the compliment "architecture" and call it a substitute, quick fix, workaround, stop-gap, you are set up to follow up with "time to send it packing."

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The word **remit** can be used in a broadened sense, applied to inanimate concepts / devices designed to fulfil a purpose.

> *remit*
>
> 1. [countable noun] [usually singular ...]
>
> Someone's remit is the area of activity which they are expected to
> deal with

[[Collins](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/remit)]

........................

> - *Frame has embodied the ship's remit to save life and ease suffering, both through her own actions and the leadership of her able
>   team*. [[Forces.net](https://www.forces.net/services/navy/navy-officer-honoured-giving-vital-aid-philippines)]

.......

> - *However, as I've pointed out at some length, changing a device's remit to be a great Internet browser with a huge display does usually
>   come with some compromises, namely price, size ...* [[Steve
>   Litchfield; All About
>   Symbian](http://www.allaboutsymbian.com/features/item/12331_Smartphone_vs_Superphone_Nokia.php)]

.......

> - *This is a new style of guitar for Córdoba ... finding new styles of playing is very much in tune with the instrument’s remit. With the EQ
>   flat and the under-saddle transducer in play, there’s detail, with a
>   particularly noticeable attack when played with the pick ....* [[Music
>   Radar](https://www.musicradar.com/reviews/cordoba-stage)]

So in this sense, 'remit' is synonymous with 'design/ed purpose':

- *This architecture has exceeded its original remit and so would benefit from major refactoring.*

Comment: that was the word, thank you!

Comment: A related word is _ambit_.

Comment: Y’all British? That’s not a word I’ve *ever* heard used in this sense.

Comment: Ah yes, you quoted Collins — not Webster as attributed. Here’s Webster: ***1
British :** an area of responsibility or authority—usually singular.*

Comment: Thanks, TH. Refreshing to see that people do check. // Yes; AHD has [mainly British]. I think the 'area/extent of authority/responsibility' sense is the default nounal sense in the UK.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe ***scope*** could cover this:

> the extent of the area or subject matter that something deals with or to which it is relevant. ([OxfordL via Google](https://www.google.com/search?q=scope%20meaning&oq=scope%20me&aqs=chrome.1.69i57j0i433i512j0i512l8.6918j1j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8))

***Utility*** is another option:

> the quality of being useful, or *the degree to which something is useful* ([Longman](https://www.ldoceonline.com/dictionary/utility))

Answer (score 0):

> I've already used "**purpose**" a lot, in a different context, and I need
> to avoid using purpose for this statement to prevent confusion.

I suggest:

> This architecture has exceeded it's original **raison d'être** and needs major refactoring.

***Raison d'être*, raison d'être** (n.)

> Reason or justification for existence [M-W](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/raison%20d%27%C3%AAtre)

> A reason or purpose for the existence of a person or thing [OED]

(Dictionaries and style guides differ on  italicization.)

---

> The ***raison d'être*** and the challenge of symbolic languages are to
> construct highly sophisticated software which would be too complicated
> or unmanageable if written in other languages. [A.C. Kakas and F.
> Sadri; *Computation Logic*](https://www.google.com/books/edition/Computational_Logic_Logic_Programming_an/N15qCQAAQBAJ?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=programming%20language%20raison%20d%27%C3%AAtre&pg=PA139&printsec=frontcover) (2003)

> First of all, since the whole point of having such an institution is
> to secure, in the best way possible, the enjoyment of fundamental
> rights, a legislature that compromises those rights without a morally
> acceptable trade in security will **exceed its justificatory bounds
> and lose its raison d'être**. [John Kleinig; *Ends and Means in
> Policing*](https://www.google.com/books/edition/Ends_and_Means_in_Policing/MpCKDwAAQBAJ?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=exceeded%20its%20raison%20d%27%C3%AAtre&pg=PT48&printsec=frontcover) (2019)

> One of the objectives was to give inventors' certificates the same
> status in the Paris Convention as have patents in that Convention.
> With the abolition—shortly before the Soviet Union ceased to
> exist—of inventors' certificates in that country, **this objective of
> the planned revision lost its *raison d'être***. [WIPO and A. Bogsch;
> *The First Twenty Five years of the World Intellectual Property Organization*](https://www.google.com/books/edition/The_First_Twenty_Five_Years_of_the_World/a7-jDwAAQBAJ?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=exceeded%20its%20raison%20d%27%C3%AAtre%20revising&pg=PA36&printsec=frontcover) (1992)

> Knowledge of the substantive solutions reached by the courts of each
> country cannot be sufficient. To conduct his comparison work, he needs
> to know the **spirit and the raison d'être of each solution**.
> [Eduoard Lambert (1900) in E. Lees and J. Viñuales; *Oxford Handbook
> of Comparative Environmental Law*](https://www.google.com/books/edition/Oxford_Handbook_of_Comparative_Environme/SxGTDwAAQBAJ?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=raison%20d%27etre%20of%20the%20the%20solution&pg=PA10&printsec=frontcover)  (2019)

Answer (score 0):

How about recasting the sentence as follows?:

*This architecture has overshot its mark and...*

Per *The Farlex Dictionary of Idioms*:

**overshoot the mark**

> To pass the intended target, typically due to poor judgment.

*A: "Did I overshoot the mark?"*

*B: "Yeah, I would back up so that your car isn't sticking out of the parking space!"
I think we overshot the mark with our estimate.*

[overshoot the mark](https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/overshoot+the+mark)

Answer (score 0):

**Purpose** is not jargon, not a technical term invested with a precise meaning, and so using "purpose" multiple times in different contexts will not cause confusion. Don't create imaginary problems for yourself like that. And don't paint yourself into a corner syntactically as you're doing with

> this architecture ... has exceeded it's [sic] original ______".

where you're looking for some noun that will supposedly add perfect clarity to your sentence. Consider introducing some *adjectives*! Adjectives are your friends.

You could say:

**This architecture has outlived its original *narrow* purpose as a stop-gap solution for [x] and must be refactored in order to address a *broader* range of problems.**